# Font awesome icons not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, font-awesome

I am having a problem with font-awesome icons. When you click on the little plus it is fine however if you click on the rest of the button it will not take you to the link.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
        <a href="google.com"> <i class="fa fa-plus" title="Edit"></i> </a></button>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/py7vA/217/

How would I fix this?

Comment: Looking at your classes, it looks like you are using bootstrap, right? If that is the case, remove the button and add `btn btn-default pull-right` to the `<a>` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't put an A tag inside BUTTON. It's wrong. Since you are using Bootstrap you can assign the same `btn` classes to A too.

```
<a href="google.com" class="btn btn-default pull-right" title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple different things one is what Ibrahim mentioned or:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p>

            <a href="google.com"> <i class="fa fa-plus btn btn-default pull-right" title="Edit"></i> </a>
    </p>
</div>
```